# ReferenceError: loadAnimation is not defined at /sketch.js:6:3

Tags: javascript, web, animation, editor, p5.js

```
var boat,groundImage; //variables declared

function preload(){
 
  boat = loadAnimation("b2.png"); //loading animation
  groundImage = loadImage("b1.jpg");
  
  
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400); //draw canvas
}

function draw() 
{
 background(180);
image(groundImage,0,0);
animation(boat,0,0); //locate animation
}
```

here is a simple code for using animation in p5.js editor. But I got an error as: ReferenceError: loadAnimation is not defined at /sketch.js:6:3

Answer (score 1):

The `loadAnimation()` function is not part of [p5.js](https://p5js.org/reference/). It is added by the [p5.play add-on](https://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/docs/classes/Animation.html). I can only assume that you have forgotten to add a reference to p5.play in your index.html because you did not include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
<script src="https://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/lib/p5.play.js"></script>
```